# How to simplify the code Using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I need to know how to implement the below logic to get the list of items with the help of LINQ without using `foreach`. Also, I need to exclude those matching Items from `item` List after adding the item into new list.

**Code**

```
List<StockResult> Stockres = new List<StockResult>();
foreach (var stkitms in item)
{
    if (Db.Stk.Any(a => a.INo == stkitms.ItemNum))
    {
      StockResult ss = new StockResult();
      ss.ItemNumber = stkitms.ItemNum;
      ss.FileName = stkitms.FileName;
      Stockres.Add(ss);
    }
}
```

Any solution to this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try this one:

```
List<StockResult> Stockres = item.Where(x=>Db.Stk.Any(a => a.INo == x.ItemNum))
                                 Select(x=> new StockResult()
                                 {
                                     ItemNumber = x.ItemNum,
                                     FileName = x.FileName
                                 }).ToList();
```

Comment: `StokeResult` should be `StockResult`